# How to set options of a dropdown using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Does anyone know how to set the options and the values of a dropdown menu using javascript or jquery? I'm using this HTML:

```
<select size="1" id="D1">
</select>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'set the options'? This is ambiguous.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You don't even necessarily need jQuery:

```
var select = document.getElementById("D1"),
    opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.value = "value";
opt.textContent = "text to be displayed";
select.appendChild(opt);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/YcskR/).

But here it is with jQuery anyway:

```
$("select#D1").append( $("<option>")
    .val("value")
    .html("text to be displayed")
);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/YcskR/1/).

Comment: I think there is a typo at this line `.html("text to be displayed");` remove semicolon at the end. It should be `.html("text to be displayed")`.

Comment: @Sivakumar Wow, almost 4 years old and it went unnoticed...fixed. Thanks for bringing that up! hahaha

Answer (score 14):

Yet another way of doing it, using `select`'s [add method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement#add%28%29):

```
var select = $("#select")[0];

select.add(new Option("one", 1));
select.add(new Option("two", 2));
select.add(new Option("three", 3));
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pc9Dz/

Or another way, by directly assigning values to the `select`'s `options` collection:

```
var select = $("#select")[0];

select.options[0] = new Option("one", 1);
select.options[1] = new Option("two", 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways. One is:

```
$("#D1").append("<option>Fred</option>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's yet another way to remove options using javascript (similar to Andrew Whitaker's answer) by using the options array:

```
var select = document.getElementById("D1");
select.options.length = 0;//remove all options
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dropdown").html("<option value='val1'>label 1</option><option value='val2' selected='selected'>label 2</option>");
```